# C code interrupt setup from manufacturer

Tags: c, handler, microcontroller, interrupt, isr

The code snippets below come from the manufacturer.  I am completely confused as to what they are trying to do.  In particular, anything to do with InterruptHandler.

Please comment on the code in the globals section.  Does this look right?

Also the various APIs included all have sticking points for me.  Are they trying to use a void pointer? ... Plenty to ask, please comment mainly on how they are suggesting the timer2 would work.

```
...

/**
  Section: Global Variables Definitions
*/

void (*TMR2_InterruptHandler)(void);

...

/**
  Section: TMR2 APIs
*/

void TMR2_Initialize(void)
{
    // Set TMR2 to the options selected in the User Interface

    // T2CKPS 1:2; T2OUTPS 1:2; TMR2ON off; 
    T2CON = 0x11;

    // T2CS LFINTOSC; 
    T2CLKCON = 0x04;

    // T2PSYNC Not Synchronized; T2MODE Software control One shot; T2CKPOL Rising Edge; T2CKSYNC Not Synchronized; 
    T2HLT = 0x08;

    // T2RSEL TMR4_postscaled; 
    T2RST = 0x02;

    // PR2 8; 
    T2PR = 0x08;

    // TMR2 0; 
    T2TMR = 0x00;

    // Clearing IF flag before enabling the interrupt.
    PIR4bits.TMR2IF = 0;

    // Enabling TMR2 interrupt.
    PIE4bits.TMR2IE = 1;

    // Set Default Interrupt Handler
    TMR2_SetInterruptHandler(TMR2_DefaultInterruptHandler);

    // Start TMR2
    TMR2_Start();
}

void TMR2_ISR(void)
{

    // clear the TMR2 interrupt flag
    PIR4bits.TMR2IF = 0;

    if(TMR2_InterruptHandler)
    {
        TMR2_InterruptHandler();
    }
}


void TMR2_SetInterruptHandler(void* InterruptHandler)
{
    TMR2_InterruptHandler = InterruptHandler;
}

void TMR2_DefaultInterruptHandler(void)
{
    // add your TMR2 interrupt custom code
    // or set custom function using TMR2_SetInterruptHandler()
}

/**
  End of File
*/
```

Thanks,
Steve

edit:
The manufacturer code includes a routine (I can't seem to add it here) for managing high-level interrupts that calls TMR2_ISR if (PIE4bits.TMR2IE == 1 && PIR4bits.TMR2IF == 1)  This would seem to negate any TMR2_DefaultInterruptHandler would it not?

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Do you know in general how interrupts work and what they are good for? What does trigger the interrupt handler? (It's possible that one interrupt handler is called for any interrupt. In that case, there must be some kind of specification (e.g. a global variable) which indicates what triggered the interrupt.)

Comment: use the code they provided and put your code in TMR2_DefaultInterruptHandler

Comment: This is just a skeleton.  What bit do you not understand, because this code does nothing useful.  Please refer to your user manual for hardware register details.  Refer to your OS manual for interrupt comms and signaling.

Comment: @Scheff this is embedded controller code, probably an outline for a timer interrupt. The timer is probably internally hard-wired to an line on the programmable interrupt controller.  The user manual will identify which line, and it's indeed possible that the handler will have to poll a memory-mapped hardware register to find out which timer fired.

Comment: 'I am completely confused as to what they are trying to do' I suspect that we cannot help you in any effective manner:(

Comment: This code is generated by MPLAB for PIC microcontrollers, if I am not mistaken. It's auto generated when you configure the project to use this timer, so the only thing you are left to do is place your code inside the `TMR2_DefaultInterruptHandler` function and it will be called in regular intervals. Alternatively, use your own separate function and use `TMR2_SetInterruptHandler` to point the handler to your function instead. The only thing I cannot possibly understand why they made `TMR2_SetInterruptHandler` accept a `void*` parameter, since it can clearly only accept a function pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The comments of Garr Godfrey and Martin James provided helpful hints. Thus, I will try to fill the possible gaps:

1. `void (*TMR2_InterruptHandler)(void);` is a global variable with a function pointer providing the current interrupt handler.
2. I would read `TMR2_ISR()` as "interrupt service routine". From the presented code, it's not clear from where it is called. Suspecting from it's name, it's reasonable to assume that it's called when the interrupt is triggered. It checks whether the global interrupt handler function pointer `TMR2_InterruptHandler` is not `NULL` and calls the pointed function in case of success.
3. If `TMR2_Initialize()` has been called before then `TMR2_InterruptHandler` points to function `TMR2_DefaultInterruptHandler()`. Thus, in this case, the latter is called from `TMR2_ISR()`.
4. `void TMR2_SetInterruptHandler(void* InterruptHandler)` is used in `TMR2_Initialize()`. It sets the current interrupt handler. (Surprise.)
   I'm a little bit puzzled because I would make it:
   `void TMR2_SetInterruptHandler(void (*InterruptHandler)())`
   This is because my daily work with C++ drilled me for "clean typing" but I remember that C is much more lax about this. (`void*` is compatible to any pointer.)
5. As Garr Godfrey already said: "put your code in TMR2_DefaultInterruptHandler"
   where it is recommended by the comment
   `// add your TMR2 interrupt custom code`

Comment: *It's not clear from where it is called but let assume that it's called when the interrupt is triggered* This is the purpose of interrupt routines. They are not called by user program.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Yes it is auto-generated code from the MCC within the MPLAB software for PIC programming.  I still am thoroughly confused at the roundabouts way things are referenced and called within C.  What I'm trying to do is use TMR2 in a one-shot mode.  What I did after the initial post was to go and try  putting some code in the TMR2_ISR section but nothing is happening so I'll go and try the TMR2_DefaultInterruptHandler routine instead.  Thanks again for your replies.

Comment: @Clancy To enable the interrupt, you have to call `TMR2_Initialize()` in your program. (Note the call at `TMR2_Start()` at end of its body.) If you've put your code into `TMR2_ISR()`, it should've been worked as well.